# Selenium Webdriver Support for Javafx 2.0 Webkit or QT5 Webkit (Goal: headless webkit)

Tags: qt, webkit, webdriver, integration-testing, javafx-2

I was wondering:

- Has anybody already thought about implementing the webdriver-interface for an embedded Javafx 2.0 Webkit Browser or for the new QT5 - Webkit.
- Has anybody some pointers on some Github/Bitbucket/GoogleCode projects heading in this direction?

Why?
This would add
another cross-platform browser and hopefully could be headless with a new webkit rendering engine.
Right now I am using SafariDriver on MacOSX or ChromeDriver. This kinda works, but chromedriver often bites me, when Chrome does it's autoupdate and breaks the chromedriver.

The project, which comes closest for a headless Webkit implementation (including taking screenshots) is, I think, phantomjs (QT-4.8 webkit) + ghostdriver (webdriver addon for phantomjs as a javascript implementation).
Right now phantomjs has it's quirks with fonts and hyphenation (­) rendering.

Testing the QT5 browser examples, the font/shy rendering seems to have been fixed.
Now I could either wait for phantomjs to catch up with qt5.

The other idea would be to have Java 7 installed, which includes Javafx 2.0 and implement a WebView which can be controlled by the webdriver-protcol as well. Newer JavaFx 2.0 version contain the possibility to take screenshots of JavaFX scenes, which would be helpful.

References:

- http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2012/03/the-evolution-of-phantomjs-build-workflow.html (Phantomjs/QT integration)
- [How to fix/work around QtWebKit's incorrect font fallback behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769169/how-to-fix-work-around-qtwebkits-incorrect-font-fallback-behavior) (qt4.x font rendering)

Merry Christmas,

Jan

Comment: JavaFX WebView currently doesn't support headless offscreen snapshots.  The feature request to track for this, vote for or comment on is [RT-26571 "Provide support for taking full page snapshots from webviews"](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-26571)

Comment: Headsup: Phantomjs 2 is still not ready, JavaFX8 webkit works for me in all tests. No rendering issues. I might go ahead and implement a JavaFX browser with JsonWireProtocol for Selenium. A pure headless JavaFX 8 webengine might be possible with OpenJFX Project Monocle, but not with th current JavaFX8 release. Hopefully Project Monocle will make it in Release 8u26

Comment: XPath support in Java FX 8 webengine is broken. This makes the web driver implementation hard. https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-30698

Comment: One could inject e.g. jquery in the webengine and map the webdriver api on it.But I guess this was kind of the idea of Selenium RC1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, I built this: https://github.com/MachinePublishers/jBrowserDriver

It runs headless by default. Snapshots, xpath, and everything else work. No browser is required, just Java 8.

Comment: Java FX seems to have a major memory leak due to orphaned media handles though. Perhaps there will be  a QT5 / Qupzilla driver one day.

Comment: I created a fork that works with JDK 11 and OpenJfx 17: https://search.maven.org/search?q=a:org.everit.forks.com.machinepublishers.jbrowserdriver

Answer (score 0):

A webdriver implementation for Qt4 and Qt5 exists: https://github.com/cisco-open-source/qtwebdriver.

It drives QtWebkit, QWidgets and QML.